# Why state doesn't update in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, timer, use-state

I am working on FreeCodeCamp Front End Libraries Projects - Build a Pomodoro Clock. [Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/front-end-libraries-projects/build-a-pomodoro-clock)

I have pretty much implemented the functionality. But one major bug is there which I am unable to understand how it is getting caused.

Complete code at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqlekb?file=index.js)

As per the requirement, the break and session timers are needed to be run in  a loop in one after another sequence. When I start the timer, it correctly starts the timer in session mode and on end of the session timer, break timer starts as expected.

But when break timer ends, the session timer does not starts back. The break timer starts again.

Following is the relevant code in startTimer method, which is invoked on user event for starting the timer-

```
  const startTimer = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) return null;

    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimerLength(prevTimerLength => {
        if (prevTimerLength > 0) return prevTimerLength - 1;
        if (isSessionMode) {
          setIsSessionMode(false);
          return breakLength;
        } else {
          setIsSessionMode(true);
        }
        return sessionLength;
      });
    }, 1000);
  };
```

I have created a state - `isSessionMode` which stores a `boolean` value for mode - either session or break, `true` by default.

Then on end of timer, I have checked if `isSessionMode` is `true`, then set the timer according to the `breakLength` and set `isSessionMode` `false`. Else, set the timer according to the `sessionLength` and set `isSessionMode` true.

Comment: please post a [mcve] here!

Comment: I have given link to the codepen for the code in the question. Have you missed it or you are asking for its stripped down version?

Comment: you should post the problem code here

Comment: Okay, I have stripped down some code to keep it relevant to the problem and have updated the link. But I have to keep some extra code as well to keep the app working in order to reproduce the problem.